# How to change UID and GID for www-data in WordPress container to match the host in linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**My problem**: after docker-compose up -d of yml with wordpress service where the workdir volume is set like this:

```
services:                                                    
 wp:
  image: "wordpress:5.3.2"
  volumes:
    - ".:/var/www/html"
```

I get all wp files with different owner than the host (UID=33). This makes it difficult for me to work with these files.

**My goal**: is to change container UID and GID to 1000 (host) instead of 33 (wp container) with just docker-compose file and without running into other related issues.

**I tried** to add some commands to my compose file to do so but it didn't work:

```
command: [
    'usermod -u 1000 www-data',
    'groupmod -g 1000 www-data'

]
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The same as `docker run` command's [`--user`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user).

```
services:                                                    
 wp:
  image: "wordpress:5.3.2"
  user: "1000:1000"
  volumes:
    - ".:/var/www/html"
```